# How to remove controller name from url in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, controller

i am working on a web project in asp.net mvc.
This is code in my RouteConfig

This is url

localhost:55960/Home/myAction/80102/Aus-won-the-match-by-9-wickets

but i want to make it like

localhost:55960/myAction/80102/Aus-won-the-match-by-9-wickets

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{Title}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, Title = "" }
                );
```

I have applied many suggestions available on this platform but not worked. 
Is there any one who can explain in detail

Comment: What is the motivation behind your question? Are you trying to obfuscate the code-level name of a controller or are you trying to simplify the URL as per Isaack Rasmussen's answer?

Comment: this is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57799273/how-to-remove-controller-name-from-url-in-mvc-project/57799331#57799331

Answer (score 1):

So you want your controller to be at the root, like domain.com/?id=1 or domain.com/list?id=1
instead of domain.com/controller/list?id=1 ?

You can add to your config

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

Then for that controller,

```
[RoutePrefix("")]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

But this may get confusing to keep track of if you have many controllers.
And it may be better to configure routes.MapRoute() to point to a default controller